# Referencing namespaced LESS variables from siblings.. possible?

Tags: variables, namespaces, less

I am currently using the following strategy in my LESS files:

```
//variables
#namespace() { 
  #child1() {
    @variable1: ..
    @variable2: ..
  } 

  #child2() {
    @variableA: ..
    @variableB: ..
    @variableC: ..
  } 
}

//style
.namespace {
  #namespace();

  .child1 {
    #child1();
    width: @variable1;
  } 

  .child2 {
    #child2();
    width: @variableA;
    height: @variableC;
  } 
}
```

Not sure whether this is the best approach.

It works, however I now need to reference `@variableC` in `#child1`.

Is something like this possible?

```
#namespace() { 
  #child1() {
    @variable1: ..
    @variable2: ..
    @variable3: #child2() > @variableC;
  } 

  #child2() {
    @variableA: ..
    @variableB: ..
    @variableC: ..
  } 
}
```

And what if I need to import `child2()` variables inside another namespace? Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's impossible to access a namespaced variable with a oneliner statement. However you can do it just the same way you use in the "styles" block, just expand `#child2`  inside `#child1`:

```
// variables

#namespace() { 
    #child1() {
        @variable1: 1;
        @variable2: 2;
        #child2();
        @variable3: @variableC;
    } 

    #child2() {
        @variableA: A;
        @variableB: B;
        @variableC: C;
    } 
}

// styles

.namespace {
    #namespace();

    .child1 {
        #child1();
        width:  @variable1;
        height: @variable3;
    } 

    .child2 {
        #child2();
        width:  @variableA;
        height: @variableC;
    }
}
```

This obviously makes `#child1` to be a `#child1`/`#child2` combo so things get more tricky if the variable you need to reference has a name already used in the `#child1` itself. In that case you will need to put the referencing variable into another scope, something like this:

```
// variables

#namespace() { 
    #child1() {
        @apple:  1;
        .-; .-() {
            #child2();
            @banana: @apple;
        }
    }

    #child2() {
        @apple:  3;
        @banana: 4;
    }
}

// styles

.namespace {
    #namespace();

    .child1 {
        #child1();
        width:  @apple;
        height: @banana;
    }

    .child2 {
        #child2();
        width:  @apple;
        height: @banana;
    }
}
```